# Why wp_kses() not working for rel, target of link in Wordpress

Tags: wp-kses

I am using below code for wp_kses(). But it's ignoring rel & target in the result. I want to show rel="nofolow" target="_blank" in my result (link).

```
$link = "Here is my link: <a href="my-link" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Link Text</a>" 

$allowed_tags= array(
                        'br' => array(),
                        'p' => array(),
                        'a'  => array(
                                'href'     => true,
                                'rel'      => true,
                                'target'   => true,                             
                            ),
                );


$result = wp_kses( $link, $allowed_tags );

Output result: Here is my link: <a href="my-link">Link Text</a>

Expected result: Here is my link: <a href="my-link" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: Your `$allowed_tags` looks correct. Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/353279/edit) to include the `wp_kses()` call you're using.

Comment: I just tried your code in a local WordPress installation, and it worked fine. Try turning off all plugins and using a default theme. If that makes the problem go away, then try turning your plugins back on one by one until the problem recurs. That'll tell you if this is caused by a plugin.